# How To Run This Script More Easily

Tags: ruby, macos, unix, directory

I have a Ruby script that I wrote that sorts some files in a jumble of directories based on it's file extension. It would be very difficult to sort it using a GUI, and its easier for me to just put the file in the topmost directory and let the sorter do the work.

Problem is, I'm a bit of a noob to unix scripting. What I want to be able to do is be able to run that sorter script from anywhere on my computer, without having to

```
cd Desktop/Whatever/Foo
ruby sorterscript.rb
```

just write `sortfolders` at the commandline and have the program be run.

I've tested the script many times, and it works fine, I just want a bit more convenience.

**Bonus**: If possible, and not too difficult, it would be even better if I could have the program run, say, every hour automatically.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As far as your first question goes, you need to do couple of things:

1. Add a [shebang line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29#Examples) to your script (make it the first line of the script):

   `#!/usr/bin/ruby` (or whatever the path to the Ruby interpreter's executable is, I forget its exact location)
2. Make the script executable, either via the Finder's "Get Info" context menu, or via the command line, for example:

   `chmod 755 my_script.rb`
3. Add the directory location of your script to the PATH environment variable to OS X's launchd.conf file, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/588442/1437878). You need to add this line:

   `setenv PATH /path/to/my/script:$PATH` (substitute the real path to your script)

As far as your bonus question goes, you can use cron to set up a recurring job. I never really do this, but here's [Apple's cron man page](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/Manpages/man5/crontab.5.html) to get you started.

Comment: `Dir.chdir` might also be useful. That changes the cwd of the script so, for example, the script will always run in the same directory no matter where you call it from.